# Python - как сделать выгрузку в txt?

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Допустим, у меня код:

```
# бла-бла
print("x")
print("y")
```

можно ли добавить код, чтобы содержимое print можно было сохранить в txt?
Как можно будет потом прочитать этот файл в Python?

Comment: Можно. Работа с файлами - одна из основнейших функций почти любого языка. Наверняка в сети полно информации об этом, попробуй поискать.

Answer (score 3):

Когда ваш скрипт сохранен в файле `some_script.py`, вы можете *вывести вывод до файла (например до файла*  `some_file.txt`*) вместо на консоль:*

```
python some_sript.py > some_file.txt
```

После этого вы можете читать файл `some_file.txt`:

```
with open("some_file.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # сделать что то с очередной строкой (она закончена символом "\n")
```

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @leonardik, не стоит.

Answer (score 3):

Можно также сделать через параметр `file` метода `print`. Он позволяет указать куда выводить текст, и по умолчанию равен `sys.stdout`, но можно указать и файл:

```python
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('x', file=f)
    print('y', file=f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам стоит обратиться к `Работа с файлами в Python`

> https://python-scripts.com/work-with-files-python

Прочесть **из файла input.txt** можно так:

```
handle = open("input.txt", "r")
data = handle.read()
print(data)
handle.close()
```

Записать **в файл output.txt** можно так:

```
handle = open("output.txt", "w")
handle.write("This is a test!")
handle.close()
```